# Easiest way to combine date and time strings to single datetime object using Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a web form which has 2 input fields, "StartDate" and "StartTime".  I convert the `StartDate` field's string into a Python `datetime` object, no problem.  The `StartTime` field is passed in as a string in the form "0130" for 1:30am.  What is the best way to convert the `StartTime` string and combine it with the `StartDate` `datetime` object so that both are stored as a single `datetime`?

Comment: Check `datetime.combine`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use [datetime.combine](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
import datetime as dt
mytime = dt.datetime.strptime('0130','%H%M').time()
mydatetime = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), mytime)
```

Comment: A note on readability: When the module name and class name are the same (in this case `datetime`) I prefer to use an alias to clarify.

Answer (score 14):

If you can load the time into a `datetime.time`, you can use the following code

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12)
tm = datetime.time(1, 30)

combined = dt.combine(dt, tm)

print(combined)
```

### Output

```
2012-02-12 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 10):

Just a short version:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.combine(datetime.strptime("5 Mar 12", "%d %b %y"), datetime.strptime("0130","%H%M").time())
```

**Output**

```
2012-03-05 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
def time_tango(date, time):
    return datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
```