# Convert datetime.time to seconds

Tags: python, time

I have an object of type `datetime.time`. How do I convert this to an int representing its duration in seconds? Or to a string, which I can then convert to a second representation by splitting?

Comment: Duration assumes you have two datetime.time objects and a difference of seconds between them. Are you trying to calculate the difference in seconds between two datetime.time objects?

Answer (score 35):

You can calculate it by yourself:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now().time()
seconds = (t.hour * 60 + t.minute) * 60 + t.second
```

Comment: Simple and to the point. Very good answer!
If you want to include microseconds you can also add "+ (t.microsecond/1000000)"

Comment: OP asks about `datetime.time` object not `datetime.datetime`. Those are different and not fully compatible. Your answer does not work in this case (at least in python3.11).

Answer (score 27):

You need to convert your `datetime.time` object into a `datetime.timedelta` to be able to use [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) function.

It will return a `float` rather than an int as asked in the question but you can easily cast it.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
>>> timeobj = time(12, 45)
>>> t = datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj) - datetime.min
>>> isinstance(t, timedelta)
# True
>>> t.total_seconds()
45900.0
```

Links I've be inspired by:

- [SO question on datetime.combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578906/easiest-way-to-combine-date-and-time-strings-to-single-datetime-object-using-pyt)
- [SO question about converting `datetime.time` to `datetime.timedelta`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241643/convert-datetime-time-into-datetime-timedelta-in-python-3-4)

Answer (score 6):

If your object is supposed to represent a duration, you should use a `datetime.timedelta` instead of a `datetime.time`.

[datetime.time objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#time-objects) are meant to represent a time of the day.

[datetime.timedelta objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) are meant to represent a duration, and have a `total_seconds()` method that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Neat and easily understandable explanation!

Answer (score 6):

As @Owl Max proposed the easiest way to have an integer representation of a time is to use a timedelta. Although, I would like to share a different way to construct the timedelta.

A useful one-liner I like to use is:

```
import datetime
t = datetime.time(10, 0, 5)
int(datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second).total_seconds())
```

(ps. Normally this would be a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% the answer, but might be relevant in a lot of use-cases:

Suppose you have a pd.Series of such `datetime.time` objects (in the example below, the "start" column of the `df` pd.DataFrame)

[image]

And you want to convert them at once, you can use the `pd.TimeDeltaIndex` after the `astype("str")` casting.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['start'].astype("str")).total_seconds()
```