# Subtracting datetime's in Python

Tags: python, datetime, operands

So I'm trying to implement a timing routine and I need to return the seconds (secs) so that my timing routine starts my lights. The original code that I researched got me fairly far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
    #...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

The only issue is that I took in the x.replace as a user input variable and now I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'"

I understand it's because you can't directly subtract two datetime.datetime.time() directly but I'm unsure on how to convert them into something that I can operate with. Here's my code so far

```
import datetime
from threading import Timer
import tkinter as tk
import time

# =============================================================================
# userInput takes a formatted input and passes it back to main.
# =============================================================================
def userInput():
        try:
            a = datetime.datetime.strptime(input('When would you like to routine to start in HH:MM 24 hour format: '), "%H:%M").time()
            print (a.strftime("%H:%M"))
        except:
            print ("Please enter correct time in HHMM format")
        return a

# =============================================================================
# timeComparator is a function which, if the user changes any settings or chooses
# start in the middle of a cycle, implements the correct routine depending on where
# in the cycle it's in.
# =============================================================================            
def timeComparator(a):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    #this obtains the current time
    #if statement compares input from 
    print("the time now is: ", now)
    if (now < a):
        print ("hello human")
    elif (now > a):
        print ("hello plant")

# =============================================================================
# This routine is hard coded and cannot be changed by the user. It assumes that 
# there will be a total of 12 hours of light with the last hour, in other words
# the last 8% of light, shifting from a natural blue hue to a more red hue. 
# The auto routine will start at 8am and end at 8pm. By ending, the routine 
# stops light shifting and finally at 830PM, the lights turn off.
# NOTE NOTE NOTE NOTE NOTE
# This is NOT the actual light routine. This is JUST function that records
# the time and returns the seconds that begins the start command for the lights
# =============================================================================
def autoRoutine(a):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    #this is the start of the auto routine
    start=a
    delta_t = start-now

    secs = delta_t.seconds+1
    return secs

def blueFade():
    print("the lights are starting")
# =============================================================================
# Main function. Will be used to call all other functions
# =============================================================================
if __name__=="__main__":

    a = userInput()

    timeComparator(a)

    secs = autoRoutine(a)
    lights = Timer(secs, blueFade)
    lights.start()
```

So at the end of the day, I'm unable to operate the code line

```
    delta_t = start-now
```

and because of this I can't begin the lights.start() function. I have tried using time.strptime to compare but I haven't been successful as well as time.mktime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the delta in seconds from `now()` and a time constructed from hours and minutes we can use `time.hour`, `time.minute` and `time.second` attributes.

The issue in the question's code is that it is trying to do subtraction on two datetime.time objects

```
def autoRoutine(a):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    #this is the start of the auto routine
    start=a
    delta_t = start-now

    secs = delta_t.seconds+1
    return secs
```

This produces:

```
  File "<ipython-input-18-98011edfef89>", line 65, in autoRoutine
    delta_t = start-now

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

To correct we can convert `datetime.time` to seconds. See [convert-datetime-time-to-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823178/1978785)

Applying this answer to your question we have:

```
def autoRoutine(a):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    startSeconds = ((a.hour * 60) + a.minute) * 60
    nowSeconds = (((now.hour * 60) + now.minute) * 60) + now.second
    startSeconds - nowSeconds
```

Comment: I'm implementing this now, Charlie. I do have some questions. In the first code example, I could run it as is and it was fine. Why is that different to what I have in my code? Also, I would still need to add a line to your last snippet, correct?
```
secs = startSeconds-nowSeconds
```

Comment: On the part of your question, "I would still need sec = ... " the answer is you do not have to have secs. The last expression of a python function is returned.

Comment: On the part, "why is that different" I will have to take a look tomorrow. I am away from my computer tonight.

Comment: I didn't know that about Python thank you! Also, everything works. I really appreciate it. I was pulling my hair out!