# Converting seconds to current time with the format '%H:%M:%S.f'

Tags: python, time, strftime

I'm converting a parameter of seconds in the current time in the format hh:mm:ss, but I need to convert in the format hh:mm:ss.ms but I'm not getting it.I'm using the strftime

function and I can convert to hh:mm:ss format.

```
   f_datetime = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
 
   time_cap = time.strftime(f_datetime, time.localtime(pkt_time_cap.tv_sec))

   print(time_cap)
```

```
Result: 06:08:04.%f
```

Ps1: pkt_time_cap.tv_sec is my param for seconds

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677332/using-f-with-strftime-in-python-to-get-microseconds)  i think i found a solution who is:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_cap=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(time_cap)
```

Comment: was using the time library as it allows converting seconds to current time. Is it possible with datetime?

Comment: i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823073/convert-datetime-time-to-seconds) who show us this: 

`t = datetime.now().time()



seconds = (t.hour * 60 + t.minute) * 60 + t.second

print(seconds)`