# Problem in conversion of time from datetime to datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

I have a list of datetime object `(let say datetime_obj)` Now I want only its time part .

```
datetime_obj[0] = 22-Jun-23 13:32:00
```

I'm trying this :

```
time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i)[11:], '%H:%M:%S') for I in datetime_obj]
```

But when I am printing time it showing `01-Jan-1900 13:32:00`

Basically it is attaching a random date. what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to combine date and time strings to single datetime object using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578906/easiest-way-to-combine-date-and-time-strings-to-single-datetime-object-using-pyt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call the `".strftime("%H:%M:%S")"` method on your datetime object. This way you can avoid the list comprehension method you were using.

For example, the one-liner

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

gives you the actual time printed in the format that you need from the datetime object `datetime_obj=datetime.datetime.now()`

If you need the values instead, you could access to the `.hour`, `.minute` and `.second` properties of `datetime_obj`.